# Iterating through PHP array in javascript I get error in my each statement

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a php array:

```
$array = array(‘1234’=>”Acme Company”,
    “4321”=>”CustomerX”,
    ”1056=>”CustomerY”,
    ”1058”=>”google”,
    ”1059”=>”Yahoo”,
    ”1060”=>”apple”);
```

I am attempting to create an autocomplete with this data.  so step 1 is to iterate through in javascript.

```
 var clients = '<?php echo json_encode($array);?>';
  $.each(clients, function(i,el){
            alert(i+","+el);
    });
```

When i do this, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '2847' in {“1234”:”Acme Company”,”4321”:”CustomerX,”1056”:”CustomerY”,”1058”:”google”,”1059”:”Yahoo”,”1060”:”Apple}
```

I can not figure out why.  if i `alert(clients)`, it looks like a good array..

Comment: `var clients = <?php echo json_encode($array);?>;`

Comment: Sidenote: all those curly quotes `‘ ’` - `” ”` ...... they're killing/choking your code. Use a code editor and not some Word processor.. or you may have pulled this from the web somewhere.

Comment: That ^ was meant to know whether those are part of your actual code or not. Please respond. There was a pending edit, but I for one refused it; not knowing if that was just a bad paste or not, or if it does play a role here.

Answer (score 0):

`var client_parsed = JSON.parse(client);`

and then use  `client_parsed`

Comment: You should provide an explanation for what your code does so OP/ and future visitors know.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, you had error with passing php variable into your js var.
Now it`s iterating through all of the array elements.

```
<?php
$array = ['1234'=>'Acme Company',
    '432'=>'CustomerX',
    '1056'=>'Customer',
    '1058'=>'google',
    '1059'=>'Yahoo',
    '106'=>'apple'];

    $array = json_encode($array);

    ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var clients = <?php echo $array; ?>;
    console.log(clients);
  $.each(clients, function(i,el){
            alert(i+","+el);
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: this doesn't fully explain the errors made here, sorry

Comment: Can u elaborate a little? I`m not and expert, but i can tell but there was an error with passing value to var clients.

Comment: @Fred can u explain some more, plz?

Comment: you see how the OP posted their code with all those curly quotes `‘ ’` - `” ”`? If that is the OP's actual code, then there's a problem here and you didn't make a note of it, nor has anyone else so far, except me in a comment under their question. Should my comment happen to be removed by an unknown force, then future visitors to the question may not know where "all" the errors were made; that's **if** those are their actual quotation marks.

Comment: i have edited his array to be actual "php array" i thought that it was copy/paste error not, the actual code that he used for his script.... but u have right i should have point that out

Comment: I just want the question and answer(s) to be clear and not like mud, but "crystal" ;-) The OP hasn't responded to anything yet, so it's anybody's ballgame right now.

Comment: I noticed your pending edit. You shouldn't have done that; not knowing if that's their real code and may be playing a role here. I have refused it. Always wait till OP responds to comments about it, which I did already.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `clients  = $.parseJSON(clients);` before each `(` and remove `" '` from the numbers.

Comment: You should provide an explanation for what your code does so OP/ and future visitors know.